# Calculating number of sessions with a certain pagePath

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am trying to calculate number of sessions having one specific page path as at least one of the hits within the session ("my-path"). I need to assure that it does not match for example "my-path-2" but match "my-path/something", so I am using the following expression:

```
NTH(1,SPLIT(NTH(1,SPLIT(hits.page.pagePath,'/')),'?'))
```

The complete query however yields incorrect results and it is the following:

```
SELECT 
  date,
  hostname,
  pagePath,
  EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(id) AS sumVisits
FROM (
  SELECT
    date,
    hits.page.hostname AS hostname,
    id,
    pagePath
  FROM (
    SELECT
      (NTH(1,SPLIT(NTH(1,SPLIT(hits.page.pagePath,'/')),'?'))) WITHIN RECORD AS pagePath,
      date,
      hits.page.hostname,
      hits.type,
      CONCAT(fullVisitorId, STRING(visitId)) AS id
    FROM [my-table]
    HAVING
      pagePath ="my-path" ) )
GROUP BY
  date,
  pagePath,
  hostname
```

What am I doing wrong? This query works using CONTAINS (selecting too much) but not using NTH and SPLIT functions.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
NTH(2,SPLIT(NTH(2,SPLIT(hits.page.pagePath,'/')),'?'))
```

Sometimes the saved paths start by "/" as "/my-path/p/a" instead of "my-path/p/a"; and in that case when you take the 1st element from "split" instead of the 2nd one; the query will return you an empty string.

Comment: I have just tried it and it does not work, returns no results. So that is not the issue.